# Declared property with enums?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to have a property such as color, which only accepts a certain set of colors.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
properties: {
    color: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['red', 'blue']
    }
}
```

I cannot find anything about support for enums within declared properties.  Is the only way to implement this by manually checking the values against my set of accepted values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for enums, but you could do this with an observer:

```
properties: {
  color: {
    type: String,
    default: 'red',
    observer: '_enumColor'
  }
},
_enumColor: function(newValue, oldValue) {
  var validColors = ['red','green','blue'];
  if(validColors.indexOf(newValue) === -1) {
    // Put the color back, and maybe throw in a line to throw an error
    this.color = oldValue;
  }
}
```